# How to use Not In datatable.select

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, .net-2.0

I have a DataTable (Ado.Net) with column 'Status'. This column holds the values (in each records)

**['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','White','OtherColors']**

I want to select all the rows which status value not Red,Green,Blue

What the kind of filter expression to use to select data with my proposed criteria. So i want to achive some thing like we used in sql query  ( WHERE ***Status NOT IN ('Red','Green','Blue')***

NB:This project is running .NET 2.0 i cant use linq

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have tested it, it works as desired:

```
DataRow[] filtered = tblStatus.Select("Status NOT IN ('Red','Green','Blue')");
```

The resulting `DataRow[]` contains only DataRows with `OtherColors`, `Yellow` and `White`.

If you could use LINQ i'd prefer that:

```
string[] excludeStatus = {"Red","Green","Blue"};
var filteredRows = tblStatus.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => !excludeStatus.Contains(row.Field<string>("Status")));
```

Answer (score 6):

Without Linq you can use the rowfilter of a DataView like this

```
public DataTable GetFilteredData(DataTable table, string[] filterValues)
{
    var dv = new DataView(table);
    var filter = string.join("','", filterValues);
    dv.RowFilter = "Status NOT IN ('" + filter + "')";
    return dv.ToTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your datatable is part of a typed dataset you can use Linq to datasets, from which you could something like:

```
var records = 
      from record in datatable
      where !record.Status.Contains('Red','Green','Blue')
      select record;
```

Even if you don't have a typed dataset Linq to datasets is your answer. You would need to some casting, but not to difficult.

Comment: This project is running .NET 2.0 i cant use linq