# Optimizing query that uses AsEnumerable and SingleOrDefault

Tags: c#, sql, extension-methods, lambda-calculus

Not long ago there was a feature request in the program I am maintaining. Basically it has to fill up a table in the database with info from a text file. These files can be pretty big, but it was fairly easy to do because these files were defined as the complete list of user data. Therefore the table could be truncated and the just filled up again with data from the text file.

But then a week ago it was decided that these files are actually updates of current user info, so now I have to retrieve the correct MeteringPointId (which only exist once if it does exist) and then update info on it. If it doesn't exist, just insert data as before.

The way I do this is retrieving the complete database table with data from the database into memory and then just updating on that info before finally saving the changes by calling the datatables update function. It works fine, except that finding the row with the MeteringPointId is slow:

```
DataRow row = MeteringPointsDataTable.NewRow();

// this is called for each line in the text file to find the corresponding MeteringPointId. It can be 300.000 times.
row = MeteringPointsDataTable.AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("MeteringPointId").ToString() == MeteringPointId);
```

Is there a way to retrieve a DataRow from a DataTable that is faster than this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that only one item con fullfil the condition use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Single`. Thus you won´t collect the whole table but only the first entry you´ve found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Select* method of DataTable.

```
var expression = "[MeteringPointId] = '" + MeteringPointId + "'";
DataRow[] result = MeteringPointsDataTable.Select(expression);
```

Also you can create an expression like,

```
var idList = new []{"id1", "id2", "id3", ...};
var expression = "[MeteringPointId] in " + string.Format("({0})", string.Join(",", idList.Select(i=> "'"+i+"'")));
```

Similar usage is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359719/how-to-use-not-in-datatable-select)

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole table in a dictionary:

```
        //At the start
        var meteringPoints = MeteringPointsDataTable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<string>("MeteringPointId").ToString());

        //For each row of the text file:
        DataRow row;
        if (!meteringPoints.TryGetValue(MeteringPointId, out row))
        {
            row = MeteringPointsDataTable.NewRow();
            meteringPoints[MeteringPointId] = row;
        }
```